# TestFlight Internal Testing show Incompatible Device

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I set my project my project build 4 into iPhone only.

[image]

And set my architecture to like that

[image]

When i uploaded to iTunesConnect,and tested on my iPad 4,from TestFlight,it show me that incompatible device.

Was it because of ARM7?or iPhone only?or custom provision profile set when I uploaded to iTunesConnect TestFlight?

Here is the results of my Build4 from TestFlight

[image]

Any help please?I really need to deliver beta to my client

Comment: What is the version of iOS on your iPad?

Comment: IOS 9.2.1...any help?

Comment: I think that's because in the supported architecture shown in your TestFlight screenshot which shows that it supports arm64 only.

Comment: And please make sure during Xcode archive, build active architecture flag is set to NO.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have set your app for iPhone/iPod touch only.
Set `Devices` as `Universal` in `Deployment info` to run your app on iPad too.